# Why does my ball in the simulation stick to the bottom of this quadratic curve and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, collision-detection, game-physics

I am using this function to snap the ball to the closest point on the curve x**2:

```
def snap_to_quadratic(position):
    # Quadratic equation: y = f(x)
    def f(x):
        return x ** 2

    # Solve for the x-coordinate on the quadratic curve that is closest to the ball's current x-coordinate
    result = opt.minimize_scalar(lambda x: (x - position[0]) ** 2 + (f(x) - position[1]) ** 2)
    closest_x = result.x

    # Calculate the y-coordinate on the quadratic curve for the closest x-coordinate
    closest_y = f(closest_x)

    # Set the ball's position to the closest point on the quadratic curve
    snapped_pos = np.array([closest_x, closest_y + 0.1])

    return snapped_pos
```

and when my initial conditions for velocity are [0,0] the ball simply sticks to the bottom of the quadratic and stays there.
This is the function used to change the velocity once the ball hits the function wall:

```
def reflect_velocity(position, velocity):
    # Quadratic equation: y = f(x)
    def f(x):
        return x**2

    # Calculate the x-coordinate of the ball's position
    position_x = position[0]

    # Calculate the y-coordinate of the quadratic wall at the ball's x-coordinate
    wall_y = f(position_x)

    # Calculate the derivative of the quadratic equation at the ball's x-coordinate
    derivative = 2 * position_x

    # Calculate the normal vector of the wall at the point of contact
    normal_vector = np.array([-1, derivative])
    normal_vector = normal_vector / np.linalg.norm(normal_vector)

    # Calculate the component of the ball's velocity in the direction perpendicular to the wall
    Vn = np.dot(velocity, normal_vector)

    # Calculate the vector in the direction of the normal
    VnN = Vn * normal_vector

    # Calculate the new velocity after the collision
    new_vel = velocity - 2 * VnN

    return new_vel
```

Is this code the problem, time interval, math?

link to github for full program to try it yourself: https://github.com/tannerross22/PersonalProjects/blob/main/quadratic_old.py

I have tried lowering the time interval which changed nothing, adding an offset to the y direction once the ball snaps to the point on the graph that it is supposed to be at which only snapped the ball back to the bottom of the curve. I have also switched the order in which the velocity is reflected and the ball is snapped back to the curve which doesn't change the "stickiness" of the ball.